# gfortran not working on my Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash

I tried running `gfortran` on my Mac OS X, but it wouldn't work. When typing `gfortran` in the terminal I got the error

> -bash: gfortran: command not found.

So I thought maybe my installation was not done well, and I ran the command `apropos fort`, but I got the following:

> tk_menuBar(ntcl), tk_bindForTraversal(ntcl) - Obsolete support for menu bars
>   gfortran(1)              - GNU Fortran compiler
>   tk_menuBar(ntcl), tk_bindForTraversal(ntcl) - Obsolete support for menu bars

What does this mean and how do I get my `gfortran` working?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Fortran by using `brew install gcc`.

Get XCode command line tools from XCode preferences->downloads or here:https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=command%20line%20tools#

Get brew here:
`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`